# Using enum with select in a form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

**user.rb**

```
enum gender_type: [:male, :female] 
scope :gender, -> (gender_type) { where gender_type: gender_type}
```

**userscontroller**

```
@users = User.gender(params[:gender_type]).paginate(page: params[:page]) if params[:gender_type].present?
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag users_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= select_tag   ??????                                         %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => "nil", :id => "submit-gender" %>
<% end %>
```

the goal is to end up with:

> example.com/users?gender_type=0  or example.com/users?gender_type=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the mappings from a enum attribute you can [use the pluralised version of the the enum attribute name](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

```
User. gender_types 
=> { male: 0, female: 1 }
```

You can call `Hash.to_a` to get an array of pairs that you can pass to `options_for_select`. But you may want to use `.map` to transform the keys.

```
class User
  self.gender_options
    # or use the I18n module to humanize the keys
    self.gender_types.map { |k,v| [k.capitalize, v] }
  end
end

<%= select_tag 'gender', options_for_select(User.gender_options) %>
```

Comment: thanks. it should be `self.gender_types.map` and `:gender_type`

Answer (score 1):

Try that kind

```
select_tag 'gender', "<option value=0>male</option><option value=1>female</option>".html_safe
```

or smth like that

```
select_tag 'gender', options_for_select([["male",0],["female",1]])
```

and you can read rails api to find the solution
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Comment: thanks. yeah, i was kind of curious though how to do it without manually listing them (if possible) for future reference since there might be much more than two options next time. i will accept this though if no one comes along with that answer.

Answer (score 1):

(I assume you mistyped in filename `users.rb` and it is a regular `user.rb` model)

`User.gender_types` will return a hash `{"male" => 0, "female" => 1}`. Sounds easy!

`select_tag :gender_type, options_for_select(User.gender_types)`

Comment: I am getting this error.  `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method statuses for #<Class:0x007f4199c56660>):`   Also it should be `:gender_type` not :gender

Comment: Oh right, my bad, updated the answer. You need to call pluralised version of the word you pass into `enum`. You want to run `User.gender_types`.

Comment: this resulted in `{"male" => 0, "female" => 1}` being passed into the selection options. max solved it. :)

Comment: *sigh* I should have paid more attention here. Updated the answer again, forgot the `options_for_select` call.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use like this

```
<%= form_for(user) do |form| %>
    <%= form.select :gender_types, User.gender_types.keys.to_a %>
<% end %>
```

But assuming you use [Rails Internationalization I18n](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) (which I recommend) You may want to translate this enum like this in your view helper (or :

```
# app/helpers/users_helper.rb
def genders_select
  User.gender_types.map do |k,v|
    [User.human_enum_name(:gender_types, k), v]
  end
end
```

and

```
<%= form_for(user) do |form| %>
    <%= form.select :gender_types, @genders_select %>
<% end %>
```